# How to get id of a button in a form with two buttons both from type submit

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a React application. I have a form with two submit buttons. One button to preview and another button to save. I'm trying to figur out how to call different function when buttons gets clicked to submit the form.

Form:

```
<form onSubmit={load}>
<div>
    <textarea name="labels"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <textarea name="notes"></textarea>
</div>
<div
    <div>
        <Button variant="primary" id="test1" name="preview" type="submit">Preview</Button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Button variant="buy" id="test2" name="save" type="submit">Update version</Button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

the load function in onSubmit:

```
loadCostumeTemplate = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Just not working example
    if (event.target.id) functionX?
    if (event.target.id) function Y?
    // How to get the id of the clicked button?
}
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Why aren't you using `event.target.name` instead? The name is either "preview" or "save" instead of "test1" and "test2"?

Comment: Why not use the onClick event instead?

Comment: In plain javascript I would have set a click handler to capture the click of the buttons, and handled it from there.

Comment: Do you want to call same method for both the buttons?

Comment: custom != costume

Comment: The event of onSubmit contains form data. If i do a onClick will i get the same form data in the event?

Comment: For that you need to have controlled components.

Comment: Do you want to call same method for both the buttons?

Comment: @ravibagul91 Best would be two different methods instead of one method and a check inside

Comment: In that case you need onClick on button itself, and have [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) means store form elements values in state. On button click you can easily get data from state.

Comment: You should not have more than one submit button in a form. Consider the fact that a form can be submitted by having focus on it and pressing the **Return** key. The submit action doesn't necessarily originate from a button, so the button itself is irrelevant in the context of the submit event and there's no good way to distinguish between two different ones. Just think of which action you want to happen when the form is submitted by a **Return** press, make the corresponding button the one and only submit button and make the other button a regular one with an `onClick` event handler attached.

Comment: Thanks guys, i solved the issue based on your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Submitting is happening on the form level, so you can try using ref and assign proper value on button click like below:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const myForm = useRef();

  const loadCostumeTemplate = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Just not working example
    console.log(myForm.current.buttonId);
    if (event.target.id) alert("hi");
    if (event.target.id) alert("Bye");
    // How to get the id of the clicked button?
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={loadCostumeTemplate} ref={myForm}>
      <div>
        <textarea name="labels" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea name="notes" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <button variant="primary" id="test1" name="preview"  type="submit" onClick={e => myForm.current.buttonId=e.target.id}>
            Preview
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button variant="buy" id="test2" name="save" type="submit"  onClick={e => myForm.current.buttonId=e.target.id}>
            Update version
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I believe, @mark explained it better. You can use my example to do the same in react.